# Quartz package doesn't exist

Tags: java, maven, quartz-scheduler

There is project with **pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.vidmind</groupId>
        <artifactId>vidmind-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>vidmind-scheduling</artifactId>
    <name>Vidmind Scheduling Module</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-all</artifactId>
         </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**project.iml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module org.jetbrains.idea.maven.project.MavenProjectsManager.isMavenModule="true" type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
  <component name="FacetManager">
    <facet type="Spring" name="Spring">
      <configuration />
    </facet>
  </component>
  <component name="NewModuleRootManager" LANGUAGE_LEVEL="JDK_1_7">
    <output url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/classes" />
    <output-test url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target/test-classes" />
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/main/java" isTestSource="false" />
      <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/target" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="inheritedJdk" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.quartz-scheduler:quartz-all:2.1.5" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.1.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.1.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-jackson:0.1.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-json-core:0.1.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: ch.qos.logback.contrib:logback-json-classic:0.1.2" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.5" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-context:3.2.4.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-aop:3.2.4.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-beans:3.2.4.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-core:3.2.4.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-expression:3.2.4.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: org.springframework:spring-test:3.2.4.RELEASE" level="project" />
    <orderEntry type="library" scope="TEST" name="Maven: org.mockito:mockito-all:1.9.0" level="project" />
  </component>
</module>
enter code here
```

In one of java file there is

```
package com.company.commons.scheduling.manager;
import org.quartz.*;
import org.quartz.Trigger.TriggerState;
import org.quartz.impl.matchers.GroupMatcher;
```

And all lines starting with **org.quartz** complain that package **org.quartz** not found.

What I've tried.
I've copied quartz-all-2.1.7.jar file to the project folder and made `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=quartz-all-2.1.7.jar....` but without success.

Sorry in advance for likely stupid question - I'm totally noob.

Comment: The simple issue here that the artifact `org.quartz-scheduler:quartz-all:2.17`  does not exist only those: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.quartz-scheduler and a `mvn install:install-file..` is not neccessary cause Maven handles that on it's own...

Comment: @khmarbaise but I have this file locally, by mvn install command I wanted to add to the project. Is it wrong way to add a file that is absent in Maven's global repo?

Comment: Copying file into a project folder is violating the whole Idea of Maven which downloads the artifacts from Central (by default) or from a repository inside a corporate environment. And you should prefer using the existing artifacts instead of making things yourself which increases the maintenance burden...

Comment: Thank you, @khmarbaise. Please add your top comment as an answer in order to be accepted by me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple issue here that the artifact org.quartz-scheduler:quartz-all:2.17 does not exist only those: https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.quartz-scheduler and a `mvn install:install-file..` is not necessary cause Maven handles that on it's own...